# cypress - How can I get a select element by the selected value?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to use Cypress in a Vue project. I have a page where there is a table with a lot of rows. Each row has a select tag. This select tag has different options with the current status of each row eg: "In Process", "Waiting for Review", etc.

By changing this , there are some conditions; some changes from one status to the other are not allowed, some require a confirmation, some are just ok and a success message is displayed.

In order to test this I have to get the  elements based on their current value.
As I see on the cypress documentation or in different sites, there isn't an explanation for this (if it's possible).

So, to be more clear, I would want something like these (I know that `hasValue` is not something that exists on cypress):

```
cy.get('select').hasValue('In Process')
// or
cy.get('select').hasValue(3)
```

I've tried things like `contains` but this returns all the  text.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is here [Select Examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Examples),

There are various ways shown, for example using `.invoke('val')` to extract the value of the `<select>`.

```js
cy.get('select')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'In Process')

cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', 'In Process')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'Your value');